# The command git status result message not showing modified file in console

Tags: git, git-status

I'm new to git.
I was going through an exercise and noticed something strange happening. The modified line is not showing in the console when I tried to check the status. It looks like this on my screen:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Even if I select the whole section (thinking it would be a colour issue), it still blank. But if I copy and paste the results, the line appears:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   hello.rb
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: It now shows the modified files. Haven't changed anything...

Answer (score 0):

```
git config --global color.ui false
```

will disable colored output. i assume it has to do with it.